# How can I get Items to show in my QListWidget before the end of the function?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want my `QListWidget` to update with the new item as it is added, but it only updates with all of the items once the function has ended. I have tried using `update()` and `repaint()`, but neither work. I actually had to use `repaint()` on the Widget itself just to get it to show up before the end, but none of the items do. Here is a brief view of the first item to add:

```
def runPW10(self):
    self.PWList.setVisible(True)
    self.PWList.setEnabled(True)

    # This repaint() has to be here for even the List to show up
    self.PWList.repaint()

    ....

    self.PWList.addItem('Executing Change Password Tool')

    # This does not help
    self.PWList.repaint()

    ....
```

There is more to the function, but it is long and this should include what it needed. Please let me know if more is required.

What am I doing wrong that makes this List not update as the item is added?

Comment: `addItem()` does not return anything so `x` will always be None.

Comment: It was just something I was testing. It actually isn't in my code; I just forgot to take it out here. It is now edited out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`QApplication.processEvents()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents).

> `QCoreApplication.processEvents (QEventLoop.ProcessEventsFlags flags = QEventLoop.AllEvents)`
>
> Processes all pending events for the calling thread according to the specified flags until there are no more events to process.
>
> You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation (e.g. copying a file).

Your widget originally will be shown but unresponsive. To make the application responsive, add `processEvents()` calls to some whenever you add an item.

Do keep in mind that this can affect performance *a lot*. This lets the whole application loop execute including any queued events. ***Don't*** add this to performance sensitive loops.

Also consider that this allows your user to interact with the application, so make sure that any interactions that can happen either are not allowed, such as `somebutton.enabled(False)`, or are handled gracefully, like a `Cancel` button to stop a long task.

See the [original C++ docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) for further information, since `pyqt` is a direct port.

Comment: This looks like it. Thank you so much! I have been trying to hours searching and testing with no results.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Drise's answer on this point:

> Also consider that this allows your user to interact with the application, so make sure that any interactions that can happen either are not allowed, such as `somebutton.enabled(False)`, or are handled gracefully, like a `Cancel` button to stop a long task.

You may want to use the [`QEventLoop.ExcludeUserInputEvents`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qeventloop.html#ProcessEventsFlag-enum) flag this way: `QCoreApplication.processEvents(QEventLoop.ExcludeUserInputEvents)` to refresh the GUI while preventing the user to activate any widgets.

> `QEventLoop.ExcludeUserInputEvents`
>
> `0x01`
>
> Do not process user input events, such as `ButtonPress` and `KeyPress`. Note that the events are not discarded; they will be delivered the next time `processEvents()` is called without the `ExcludeUserInputEvents` flag.

Comment: That is good to know as well. Thank you, I shall add that in.

Comment: I didn't explicitly know about that flag. Neat. Added a direct link to the docs.